# C# Regex, any more efficient way to parse string enclosed by symbol?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm not sure if it's okay to ask... But here goes.

I implemented a method that parses a string using regex, each matching are parsed through the delegates with an order ( actually, order is not important-- I think, wait, is it? ... But I wrote it this way, and it's not fully tested ):

- Pattern Regex.Replace: `@"(?<!\\)\$.+?\$"` then String.Replace: `@"\$", @"$"`; Replace string enclosed by dollar sign. Ignores backslash ones, then erases backslash. Ex: "$global name$" -> "motherofglobalvar", "Money \$9000" -> "Money $9000"
- Pattern Regex.Replace `@"(?<!\\)%.+?%"` then String.Replace `@"\%", @"%"`; Replace string enclosed by percentage sign. Ignores backslash ones, then erase backslash. Same as previous example: "%local var%" -> "lordoflocalvar", "It's over 9000\%" -> "It's over 9000%"
- Pattern Regex.Replace `@"(?<!\\)@"` then String.Replace `@"\@", @"@"`; Replace char '@' with whitespace, ' '. But ignore backslash ones, then erase the backslash. Ex: "I@hit@the@ground@too@hard" -> "I hit the ground too hard", "qw\@op" -> "qw@op"

What I've done without much experience (I think):

```
//parse variable
    public static string ParseVariable(string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\\)\$.+?\$", match =>
        {
            string trim = match.Value.Trim('$');
            string trimUpper = trim.ToUpper();
            return variableGlobal.ContainsKey(trim) ? variableGlobal[trim] : match.Value;
        }).Replace(@"\$", @"$"), @"(?<!\\)%.+?%", match =>
        {
            string trim = match.Value.Trim('%');
            string trimUpper = trim.ToUpper();
            return variableLocal.ContainsKey(trim) ? variableLocal[trim] : match.Value;
        }).Replace(@"\%", @"%"), @"(?<!\\)@", " ").Replace(@"\@", @"@");
    }
```

In short, what I used is: `Regex.Replace().Replace()`

Since I need to parse 3 kinds of symbols, I chained it as following: `Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace().Replace()).Replace()).Replace()`

Is there any more efficient way than this? I mean, like without need to go through the text 6 times? (3 times regex.replace, 3 times string.replace, where each replace modifies the text to be used by the next replace )

Or is it the best way it can do?

Thanks.

Comment: THis `.Replace(@"\%", @"%")` would replace a `%` with `%`, inorder to replace `\%` with `%`, your pattern must be `.Replace(@"\\%", @"%")`

Comment: If you didn't know, that is a Verbatim string that begins with @, it is being read as literal characters, the escape sequences is not parsed, ex: "\\" is not parsed as "\", and it remains as "\\". Your example turns out that the result ends up "\\%" -> "\%" instead of "%".

I find it odd you just pointed out only that part, because there's more.

Comment: Have you considered going to a full parser like ANTLR http://www.antlr3.org?

Comment: Hm, I tried looking for best way to parse text commands. But unfortunately, I don't know if those parsers can do something what I did like this: 

"TextBox, [Options]". 

The [Options] has many parameters (about 30+ or more), they can be left out as default, and freedom arrangement. For example: 

"TextBox, Name=Qufad, Clear, ShowName, Draw, DrawBack, Show".  
Example 2: "TextBox, BorderLeft=Twice, BorderRight=Twice, BorderTop=Half, BorderBottom=Auto". 

Although I have to implement a large switch-case statement to parse everything correctly. All of these commands calls method or modify field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a unique take on the problem, I think. You can build a class that will be used to construct the overall pattern piece-by-piece. This class will be responsible for the generating of the `MatchEvaluator` delegate that will be passed to `Replace` as well.

```
class RegexReplacer
{
    public string Pattern { get; private set; }
    public string Replacement { get; private set; }
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }
    public RegexReplacer NextReplacer { get; private set; }

    public RegexReplacer(string pattern, string replacement, string groupName, RegexReplacer nextReplacer = null)
    {
        this.Pattern = pattern;
        this.Replacement = replacement;
        this.GroupName = groupName;
        this.NextReplacer = nextReplacer;
    }

    public string GetAggregatedPattern()
    {
        string constructedPattern = this.Pattern;
        string alternation = (this.NextReplacer == null ? string.Empty : "|" + this.NextReplacer.GetAggregatedPattern());   // If there isn't another replacer, then we won't have an alternation; otherwise, we build an alternation between this pattern and the next replacer's "full" pattern

        constructedPattern = string.Format("(?<{0}>{1}){2}", this.GroupName, this.Pattern, alternation);    // The (?<XXX>) syntax builds a named capture group. This is used by our GetReplacementDelegate metho.

        return constructedPattern;
    }

    public MatchEvaluator GetReplaceDelegate()
    {
        return (match) =>
        {
            if (match.Groups[this.GroupName] != null && match.Groups[this.GroupName].Length > 0)    // Did we get a hit on the group name?
            {
                return this.Replacement;
            }
            else if (this.NextReplacer != null)                                                     // No? Then is there another replacer to inspect?
            {
                MatchEvaluator next = this.NextReplacer.GetReplaceDelegate();

                return next(match);
            }
            else
            {
                return match.Value;                                                                 // No? Then simply return the value
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It should be obvious as to what `Pattern` and `Replacement` represent. `GroupName` is kind of a hack to let the replacement evaluator know which `RegexReplacer` fragment resulted in the match. `NextReplacer` points to another replacer instance that holds a different pattern fragment (et al.).

The idea here is to have a kind of linked list of objects that will represent the overall pattern. You can call `GetAggregatedPattern` on the outer-most replacer to get the full pattern--each replacer calls the next replacer's `GetAggregatedPattern` to get that replacer's patter fragment, to which it concatenates its own fragment. The `GetReplacementDelegate` generates a `MatchEvaluator`. This `MatchEvaluator` will compare its own `GroupName` to the `Match`'s captured groups. If the group name was captured, then we have a hit, and we return this replacer's `Replacement` value. Otherwise, we step into the next replacer (if there is one) and repeat the group name comparison. If there is no hit on any replacer, then we simply yield back the original value (i.e. what was matched by the pattern; this should be rare).

The usage of such might look like this:

```
string target = @"$global name$ Money \$9000 %local var% It's over 9000\% I@hit@the@ground@too@hard qw\@op";
RegexReplacer dollarWrapped = new RegexReplacer(@"(?<!\\)\$[^$]+\$", "motherofglobalvar", "dollarWrapped");
RegexReplacer slashDollar = new RegexReplacer(@"\\\$", string.Empty, "slashDollar", dollarWrapped);
RegexReplacer percentWrapped = new RegexReplacer(@"(?<!\\)%[^%]+%", "lordoflocalvar", "percentWrapped", slashDollar);
RegexReplacer slashPercent = new RegexReplacer(@"\\%", string.Empty, "slashPercent", percentWrapped);
RegexReplacer singleAt = new RegexReplacer(@"(?<!\\)@", " ", "singleAt", slashPercent);
RegexReplacer slashAt = new RegexReplacer(@"\\@", "@", "slashAt", singleAt);
RegexReplacer replacer = slashAt;
string pattern = replacer.GetAggregatedPattern();
MatchEvaluator evaluator = replacer.GetReplaceDelegate();
string result = Regex.Replace(target, pattern, evaluator);
```

Because you want each replacer to know if it got a hit, and because we are hacking this by using group names, you want to make sure that each group name is distinct. A simple way to ensure this would be to use a name that's identical to the variable name since you can't have two variables with the same name within the same scope.

You can see above that I am building each part of the pattern separately, but as I build, I pass the previous replacer as a 4th parameter to the current replacer. This builds the chain of replacers. Once built, I use the last replacer constructed in order to generate the overall pattern and evaluator. If you use anything but, then you will only have part of the overall pattern. Finally, it's simply a matter of passing the generated pattern and evaluator to the `Replace` method.

Keep in mind that this approach was targeted more at the problem as described. It may work in more general scenarios, but I've only worked with what you've presented. Also, since this is more of a parsing question, a parser may be the proper route to take--although the learning curve is going to be higher.

Also keep in mind that I haven't profiled this code. It certainly doesn't loop over the target string multiple times, but it does involve additional method calls during replacement. You would certainly want to test it in your environment.

Comment: *Upvotes-- needs 15 reputation to show up?* Thank you for your effort! Lemme test... *Tests* ... Hmm, I've attempted to make your code does what I want, and I discovered that it's 2.2x slower! :o I attempted to optimize it, and it became 1.5x slower. So I optimized it further, it became 1.45x slower, now 1.39x slower if I use int for GroupName. I'm not sure how to optimize further, but it seems slightly inefficient. :o

Comment: I can't look into it at the moment as I am at work, but I'll try to look at it later this evening. One thing I forgot to mention is that it may be beneficial to order the `RegexReplacer`s in order of frequency descending (i.e. the replacer whose pattern is least occurring would be declared first; the most occurring would be the last one declared). This may or may not be possible for your data.

Comment: Also, roughly how large of a string are we talking here? As in, how many characters is the string, and how many potential replacements?

Comment: Ah, sorry to bother you while you're at work. :o Oh, well I'm doing a self-implemented visual novel code to parse them. So basically I aren't parsing a large string, but over thousand or even ten thousand of lines of strings. Each function (except variable parameter) in those code are upper-cased & space-trimmed for switch-case recognition. To parse, just as illustrate in my example, I need to replace $globalvar$, %localvar%, @, \$, \%, and \@. The $globalvar$ and %localvar% needs to go through a dictionary lookup as well. I thought if there's more efficient way than my own implementation. :D